# How to run multiple distros using lvm

Tags: dual-boot, lvm, mint

I've seen quite a few posts around about running multiple distros but not sure they apply to using LVM (and without Windows). I'm using a machine that's about 3 years old.  Setup:

```
 Intel Core i7 2.8GHz
 8GB Ram
 1TB SATA HDD
```

At this point, I'd like to install 12.10 and Mint 14, leaving the option open to install additional distros down the road.

I could be way off, but I'm thinking about creating at least 2 primary `/boot` partitions (1 for 12.10 and 1 for Mint) and another partition for LVM leaving room for additional `/boot` partitions.  Then creating a VG and separate LVs for Ubuntu 12.10 and Linux Mint 14.  I understand I can share partitions between the 2 installs, but I'm only using this for testing and I have tons of space to play with.  LVM seemed logical considering I may want to install and test additional distros.  I guess I could share the `/swap` partition across the board without problems, right?

I'm unclear about GRUB2.  How do I handle the bootloader situation? Install 12.10 and get it running then make changes to grub.cfg after installing Mint?  And do I not install GRUB for Mint or do I install it in a different location?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With grub2 you do not need a separate /boot partition.  You can either have the other distros not install a boot loader, or reinstall the Ubuntu grub2 and when you run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu, it will detect the other installations and add them to the menu.

Note that the last time I tried this with Mint, its installer did not seem to recognize LVM.